# awk: print everything but not the last nth columns

Tags: awk

I have an input file in this form:

```
foo bar 08 320984 2384
bla foo baz 23 32425 32532
[...]
```

there are always three tokens in the end, but an unknown number of tokens in the front. I want to rewrite the file as CSV so it can be automatically parsed by other applications.  my current awk command is:

```
awk '{ print $(NF-2)";"$(NF-1)";"$NF}'
```

the output should be

```
foo bar;08;320984;2384
bla foo baz;23;32425;32532
[...]
```

Comment: That's not `CSV` but that's not the point. You are trying to split your file into four output fields? Where the last three fields are the last three fields of the input and the first field is everything else on the line?

Comment: How do you know what is token? Any text with no numbers?  You have two words in one line and three words in another.

Comment: @Jotne from the sentence "there are always three tokens in the end, but an unknown number of tokens in the front" I understand it is always like `tk1 tk2 tk3 ... tkn TK1 TK2 TK3` and has to become `tk1 tk2 tk3 ... tkn;TK1;TK2;TK3`.

Comment: @fedorqui So in short, add `;` for the last thee fields?

Comment: @Jotne in front each one of the last three, exactly.

Comment: @fedorqui Then my new post should fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you and fedorqui properly:

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<NF;i++) printf "%s%s",$i,(i+4>NF?";":FS);print $NF}' file
foo bar;08;320984;2384
bla foo baz;23;32425;32532
```

This will add `;` in front of the last three fields.

[John's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26745601/awk-print-everything-but-not-the-last-nth-columns/26745725#comment42077125_26745808) may be better way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

This is unfortunately something that awk just isn't the greatest at (and `cut`'s ability to do field ranges doesn't help here either.

Something like this should work though:

```
awk '{nfff=$(NF-2); nff=$(NF-1); nf=$NF; NF-=3; printf "%s;%s;%s;%s\n", $0, nfff, nff, nf}' file
```

Comment: A small variation on your approach: `$ awk '{ last=";"$(NF-2)";"$(NF-1)";"$NF; NF-=3; print $0 last}' file`

Answer (score 1):

`sed` could also work:

```
sed 's/\ \([^\ ]\+\)\ \([^\ ]\+\)\ \([^\ ]\+\)$/;\1;\2;\3/' file
```

or if your `sed` supports `-r`:

```
sed -r 's/\ ([^\ ]+)\ ([^\ ]+)\ ([^\ ]+)$/;\1;\2;\3/' file
```

It replaces the last 3 newlines with `;`.

Or a bit **easier**:

```
rev file | sed 's/\ /;/g; s/;/\ /g4' | rev
```

Answer (score 1):

A fancy GNU awk method:

```
gawk '
    function replace(what) {
        return gensub(/[[:blank:]]+([^[:blank:]]+)$/, ";\\1", 1, what)
    }
    {$0 = replace(replace(replace($0))); print}
' file
```

```
foo bar;08;320984;2384
bla foo baz;23;32425;32532
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it for an arbitrary number of fields before the last three:

```
awk '{for (i=1; i <= NF - 3; i++) if (i == 1) printf $i; else printf " "$i} {print ";"$(NF-2)";"$(NF-1)";"$NF}' input
```

Answer (score 0):

I am new to awk, but how about this (this will not remove the blank spaces though.):

```
awk '{for (i=0; i<3; i++) {$(NF-i)=";" $(NF-i)} print $0} ' file
```

Example:

```
sdlcb@Goofy-Gen:~/AMD$ cat file
foo bar 08 320984 2384
bla foo baz 23 32425 32532

sdlcb@Goofy-Gen:~/AMD$ awk '{for (i=0; i<3; i++) {$(NF-i)=";" $(NF-i)} print $0} ' file
foo bar ;08 ;320984 ;2384
bla foo baz ;23 ;32425 ;32532
```